# How to optimise an image pixelation program

Tags: c, performance, optimization, profiling, cpu

I have written some serial code which I would like to optimise as much as possible before I parallelise it using OpenMP. The program reads in a PPM file by iterating through the pixel data in 4x4 cells (variable `c`),  then it finds the average RGB value of each of those 4x4 cells, and then finally writes to a new file by outputing the average colour value, again of each of the 4x4 cells. This creates a sort of mosaic/pixelation effect.

Having performance profiled my code, the main bottlenecks are `fscanf` and `fprintf`. I am ignoring execution time to read/write to disk, so these two functions do not matter.

My effort to optimise so far:

- Loop jamming: There are two nested FOR loops within the code which have the exact same loop conditions. However, the second set of nested FOR loops requires that the functions needed to calculate the average RGB value are kept outside of that specific set. The average RGB value calculations are then needed for use in the third set of nested FOR loops (which have the same loop conditions as the second set). Because of this, I have struggled to combine the second and third sets of nested FOR loops despite their similarity.
- Loop invariant computations: I have tried to move certain operations outside of the loop where possible, but this has proven to be difficult.

**To summarise:** How can I optimise this program to reduce the execution time as much as possible?

My code:

```
typedef struct {                                //struct holding RGB type int
    int r, g, b;    //12 bytes
} pixelInt;
typedef struct {                                //struct holding RGB type unsigned char
    unsigned char r, g, b;  //3 bytes
} pixel;

int c = 4;             // Variable of 4x4 grids
int width, height;    //image variable declarations

//Raw 1 dimensional store of pixel data - will contain all the data for each pixel in the image
pixel *data = (pixel *)calloc(width * height, sizeof(pixelInt));

//Loop through entire input image 
        for (int yy = 0; yy < height; yy += c)
        {
            for (int xx = 0; xx < width; xx += c)
            {
                //the total colour of cell of size 'c'
                pixelInt cell_tot = { 0, 0, 0 };        //zero initialize struct containing mosaic cell pixel totals.

                unsigned int counter = 0; //the counter for how many pixels are in a 4x4 cell

                int bx = xx + c;  //used in loop conditions
                int by = yy + c;

                // Store each color from the cell into cell_tot struct
                for (int y = yy; y < by; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = xx; x < bx; x++)
                    {
                        unsigned int index_1d = x + y * width;      //calculate 1d index from x-index (x), y-index(y) and width;

                        unsigned char r, g, b; //maximum vales are 255, i.e. unsigned char data type                    

                        fscanf(f, "%hhu %hhu %hhu", &r, &g, &b); //%hhu is unsigned char specifier

                        //store the pixel value into data array
                        data[index_1d].r = r;
                        data[index_1d].g = g;
                        data[index_1d].b = b;

                        counter++; //increment counter

                        //average pixel color of cell
                        cell_tot.r += r;
                        cell_tot.g += g;
                        cell_tot.b += b;

                    }
                }

                //average colour of cell found by dividing cell total by loop counter 
                pixel cell_average;
                cell_average.r = cell_tot.r / counter;
                cell_average.g = cell_tot.g / counter;
                cell_average.b = cell_tot.b / counter;

                //Loop through the new image in cells of size c 
                for (int y = yy; y < by; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = xx; x < bx; x++)
                    {
                        unsigned int index_1d = x + y * width;      //calculate 1d index from x-index (x), y-index(y) and width;

                        //Assign average cell value to the pixels in the cell
                        data[index_1d].r = cell_average.r;
                        data[index_1d].g = cell_average.g;
                        data[index_1d].b = cell_average.b;

                        //Output the average colour value for the image  
                        fprintf(f_output, "%hhu %hhu %hhu \t", data[index_1d].r, data[index_1d].g, data[index_1d].b);
                    }
                    fprintf(f_output, "\n");    //Prints new line 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using a textual format for your image is easily going to be the biggest bottleneck here.

Comment: It's part of the specification that I read/write in textual format @ybungalobill

Comment: Try reading the full file before the loop into a buffer and `sscanf` from the buffer, then write the result into a separate buffer and write the result to file at the end.

Comment: This should be on CodeReview not StackOverflow

Comment: I had no idea CodeReview was a thing. Would you suggest I post on there?

Comment: @p.luck: Is your code even correct? You read sequential 16 pixels from **one row** and then average *them* into one pixel.

Comment: @ybungalobill You are correct, I had problems reading the data in a non-linear fashion. I can kind of get the program functioning on one PPM image and it seems to pixelate it okay, so I have decided to leave it as it is for the time being.

Comment: OT: regarding: `pixel *data = (pixel *)calloc(width * height, sizeof(pixelInt))`  1)  the returned type, in C, is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug,  Suggest removing that 'cast'

Comment: the posted code fails to take into account that row of pixels must contain a count of pixels that is a multiple of 2.  So always have to round up the 'width' to a multiple of 2

Comment: When asking a question, about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct {                                //struct holding RGB type unsigned char
    unsigned char r, g, b;  //3 bytes
} pixel;`  one of the fields in the image header states how many bites are in each pixel.  Depending on the specific image, that can be 1byte, 2bytes, 3bytes, 4bytes per pixel

Comment: OT:  variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both).  Names like `xx` `yy` `bx` `by`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context.  I.E. Please use meaningful names, not 1 or 2 letter random sequences

Comment: the posted code is failing to check that the `4x4` grid does not exceed the boundary of the pixel data Either horizontally nor vertically

Comment: regarding: `f_output`  The expectation is that this a `FILE *`  but such a file is never opened (not closed) in the posted code

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()` Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()`, cleanup, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `int width, height;    //image variable declarations

//Raw 1 dimensional store of pixel data - will contain all the data for each pixel in the image
pixel *data = (pixel *)calloc(width * height, sizeof(pixelInt));`   The variables `width` and `height` are being used uninitialized

Comment: regarding: `//average pixel color of cell
                        cell_tot.r += r;
                        cell_tot.g += g;
                        cell_tot.b += b;`  This contains the sum of ALL the pixels, not just one row or one 4x4 block

Comment: @user3629249 Really appreciate the effort you went through to help me, I've used your advice and have changed my code to function correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 1024x1024 image on my machine your code executes in `0.325s`. The following code executes in `0.182s`:

```
unsigned w = width/c, h = height/c;
unsigned *accum = (unsigned*)malloc(3*sizeof(unsigned)*w);
char *line = (char*)malloc(12*w);
unsigned denom = c*c;

//Loop through entire input image 
for (int yy = 0; yy < h; ++yy)
{
    memset(accum, 0, 3*sizeof(unsigned)*w);

    // read and accumulate c lines
    for(int y = 0; y < c; ++y)
    {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < w; ++xx)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < c; ++x)
            {
                unsigned char r, g, b;
                fscanf(f, "%hhu %hhu %hhu", &r, &g, &b);
                accum[3*xx+0] += r;
                accum[3*xx+1] += g;
                accum[3*xx+2] += b;
            }
        }
    }

    // format a line
    for(int xx = 0; xx < w; ++xx)
    {
        char *cell = line + 12*c*xx; 
        snprintf(cell, 12, "%3u%4u%4u", accum[3*xx]/denom, accum[3*xx+1]/denom, accum[3*xx+2]/denom);
        cell[11] = '\t';
        for(int x = 1; x < c; ++x)
            memcpy(cell + 12*x, cell, 12);
    }

    // write it out times c
    line[12*w-1] = '\n';
    for(int y = 0; y < c; ++y)
        fwrite(line, 12*w, 1, f_output);
}
```

The trick here is to format the averaged values only once and then duplicate the formatted strings. Also by acting on one row at a time I have better chances of utilizing the memory caches.

To go beyond that you would need to re-implement the `fscanf` to parse the integers faster.

Comment: Thanks for posting your optimised solution. Can I ask what data type you declared variable `c` as in your code? If I define it as `unsigned int c = 0` I get this exception: `Unhandled exception at 0x008D1169 in Assignment.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero` on this line: `unsigned *accum = (unsigned*)malloc(6 * sizeof(unsigned)*w);`

Comment: @p.luck: `c` is the variable from your code and equals `4` in your example.

Comment: Of course- sorry, I wasn't thinking straight. I am however getting `Assignment.exe has triggered a breakpoint.` on the line `fwrite(line, 12 * w, 1, f_output);`. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: @p.luck: hmm, it's really hard to tell. Make sure that `w` and `width` are correct and that `width` is divisible by `c`. Double-check that you copied everything correctly.